# Passando Float para String precisamente

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net

Eu estou com um problema que no momento de conversão do meu float para string o programa esta arredondando o valor, eu passo um valor de 1050.37 e quando eu converto para String o valor retorna como 1050.4, alguém sabe como resolver?

```
public float ConvertVirgulaParaPonto(float valor)
    {
        string convertValor = valor.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat);
        var newValor = convertValor.Replace(",", ".");
        float resultado = float.Parse(newValor, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat);

        return resultado;
    }
```

Comment: não consegui replicar o problema, olha aqui que remove o culture do parse funciona: https://dotnetfiddle.net/LJ09qB

Comment: Bom eu alterei no meu código e ainda sim ele continua convertendo para .40 é estranho, não condigo encontrar ninguém com esse problema

Comment: Aqui funcionou normalmente também. O que você pode fazer é passar o formato que deseja na hora que esta convertendo para string. por exemplo: String.Format("{0:F1}", valor);

Answer (score 1):

Quando usamos float o valor é passado com Ponto(.), se vc precisa converter em string usa o CultureInfo.InvariantCulture apenas como no exemplo :

```
    public static float ConvertVirgulaParaPonto(float valor)
        {
            string convertValor = valor.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            //var newValor = convertValor.Replace(",", ".");
            float resultado = float.Parse(convertValor, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

            return resultado;
        }
```

E verifique se o retorno do método o valor está correto:

```
   static void Main(string [] args)
        {

            float meuFloat = ConvertVirgulaParaPonto(1050.37f);

           Console.WriteLine(meuFloat.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
    
                     
       
        }
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para mostrar em Console e campos de texto use o ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Não agradeça, não cumprimente nas publicações, somos um site técnico e não uma rede social.

Comment: Deu certo amigo, muito obrigado

Comment: Ótima noticia, quando tiver alguma dúvida sobre as conversões, na documentação oficial da Linguagem você encontra muita informação. https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/casting-and-type-conversions